# ¿Cómo implementar una plataforma educativa con sucursales?

Tags: php, mysql, servidor

deseo hacer un proyecto sobre una plataforma educativa, es un sistema que va a controlar Institución educativa, que cuenta con sucursales en diferentes ciudades (2 o 3 sucursales), inicialmente lo que había planteado era alojar el sistema en un hosting en internet junto a su Base de datos, con la cual podían acceder al Sistema desde cualquier sucursal y cada una de las sucursales hacer sus registros de información respectivos (Alumnos, notas, pagos, etc). Este era mi diagrama del Sistema:
[image: Propuesta Inicial para el Servidor del Sistema]

Entonces hasta ahí todo bien, pero resulta que me mencionaron que como podría hacer si el Sistema se cae osea el Hosting se cae, o en una de las sucursales se pierde la conexión a internet y no pueden acceder a la plataforma online para que registren la información como los pagos de las pensiones, las notas, etc... Entonces ahí radica mi problema, como lo muestro en la segunda imagen:
[image: ¿Qué pasa si se pierde la conexión a internet?]

Entonces me mencionaron que no querían que pase eso, ya que era usual ver esos casos en muchas entidades como bancos que a veces llegas a la entidad y te dicen que no hay sistema y no pueden realizar ninguna operación y eso genera un retraso en las operaciones y luego se saturan de clientes por atender además que genera una gran incomodidad en los clientes; entonces estuve pensando y se me ocurrió la idea de que en cada sucursal se monte una Base de datos Local en donde se va a registrar todas las operaciones de la sucursal y luego esta Base de datos local va a sincronizar a la BD Principal la cual está alojada en internet; La BD Principal debe estar alojada en internet para que pueda ser accedida desde las diferentes sucursales; y para que los docentes o el personal administrativo pueda ingresar a la plataforma online desde cualquier parte para que ingrese notas, y otros registros que sean necesarios. Esta es mi idea que plantee de montar una BD Local en cada sucursal, como lo muestro en esta imagen:
[image: Posible solución]

Quisiera que me ayuden si tal vez han trabajado con un caso parecido si mi idea puede ser válida o si habría una mejor solución, en el caso de que piensen que mi idea puede ser válida, surge la duda de ***¿Cómo sincronizo la BD Principal con las BD Locales de cada Sucursal?*** Espero su ayuda.
El proyecto lo pienso hacer con Php y Mysql.

Comment: Busca en Google "asynchronous replication".

Comment: porqué hay votos de cierre para esta pregunta? si está dentro del scope de SOes, la respuesta puede ser un poco amplia, pero igual es interesante

Comment: Te sugiero, antes que de que muera la pregunta, crear un solo sistema web y una sola base de datos, pero hostea todo si es posible en AWS, quienes te aseguran un SLA excelente, previniendo asi interrupciones en el sistema.

Comment: @Hector, yo voté para cerrarla y lo hice porque se basa en opiniones, no hay un problema específico de programación y desconozco si SO en Español tiene un alcance para este tipo de preguntas. _Nada personal, _ pero en el sitio _según la información del tour_ hay que evitar las preguntas que se basan principalmente en opiniones.

Comment: Si, visto desde ese punto de vista, tienes razón. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Porque cada sistema sucursal va tener su base de datos? Diagrama bien el sistema y que sea multisucursal, luego programas unos web services que se consuman para asi almacenar en una sola base de datos todas la sucursales, teniendo en cuenta la privacidad y los niveles de acceso. Hacer muchas bases de datos la veo ilógico.
Si sigues queriendo hacer eso, lo que debes de hacer es tener la base de datos, la cuales consumiran recursos, hay una herramienta que de oracle que se llama Stream, investiga eso porque basicamente lo que hace es replicar la informacion en las otras base de datos, asi solucionas ese problema, puedes usar joomla si vas hacer una plataforma educativa, tiene varias plantillas http://www.templatemonster.com/es/categoria/educacion-plantillas/
Ojala de haya servido!

Comment: Estimado es 1 sola BD la cual estará remotamente, pero surge el problema de que pasa que a veces se puede perder la conexión a internet y no quieren dejar de registrar la información mientras la conexión falla sino que necesitan seguir registrando todas las operaciones, sin internet.

Comment: Primero que todo es una plataforma web, si no hay internet no vas a poder acceder a la aplicación a menos que la tengas localmente en un servidor local, si es asi podrias hacer una base de datos local que cuando falle la conexión a la base de datos que tienes en la nuve te guarde una cola. Pero si sigues con la idea de hacer base de datos en cada sucursal usa Oracle Stream, investiga sobre eso.